# Inter Application Communication in opendaylight controller

Tags: network-programming, sdn, opendaylight

I am new to opendaylight and I seek help regarding following:

How can I make two different applications communicate with each other? 
Can I have something like a communication bus for my selected set of applications that can transfer data to each other? Or Do I need to have a single application with submodules (with different features ) to achieve the same task, i.e feature communication in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The main feature that sets OpenDaylight (ODL) apart from other SDN controllers is the Model-Driven Service Abstraction Layer (MD-SAL), which provides a framework to share structured/modeled data and send notifications between ODL applications, among other things.

If you want to transfer data between ODL applications, you first need to model it using [YANG](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950), and include the YANG model in one of the applications.

To take advantage of the features offered by MD-SAL, please take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/mdsal/en/stable-fluorine/index.html). Once you understand the architecture, you should look at the source code of existing applications to see examples of how to take advantage of the power of MD-SAL.